# Close Taglist window when selecting tag

Tags: vim, ctags

How would one configure the Taglist plugin to automatically close the Tagslist window after clicking on a tag? I keep the Tlist window closed due to space (my monitor stands upright, in portrait orientation) and only open it when I need to move to a tag.

This is in VIM 7.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the taglist docs:

```
Tlist_Close_On_Select - Close taglist window when a selection is made.
```

Defaults to 0 (zero), off, which doesn't close the taglist window.

```
let Tlist_Close_On_Select = 1
```

in your .vimrc will cause the taglist window to be closed after you choose.

```
:help taglist.txt
```

Will bring up the taglist docs, look at section 6, options.

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds! Congrats on finding the answer.

Comment: Even if you beat me I'd still rather give the 'accepted answer' to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's explicitly documented in the plugin's help; see `:help taglist-using`:

> To automatically close the taglist window when a tag or file is selected, you
>   can set the 'Tlist_Close_On_Select' variable to 1.  To exit Vim when only the
>   taglist window is present, set the 'Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow' variable to 1.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. I happened to find it just a few minutes after asking right on the [plugin's homepage](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/manual.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Add this to `.vimrc`:

```
let Tlist_Close_On_Select = 1
```

I am leaving the question here for the next time I need this, as Google did not help me find this the first time.

Comment: Don't just rely on Google for plugin config. Most (good) plugins ship with dedicated help pages that rival the excellent built-in help.

Comment: You are right. I've been spoiled by Google and instant-answers for the past few years.